# Calculating the average of n numbers in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a program (in Python 3) that calculates the average of n numbers, but instead of telling how many numbers I want to enter, I want the program to stop taking numbers when I enter the word "end".
For example, if I enter the following numbers:

```
1
2
3
4
end
```

it'd print

```
2.5
```

or if I entered:

```
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
end
```

the program prints:

```
13.5
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I don't have any clue what to do.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you have any code to start with? Do you know how to input a number or calculate an average? Do you know how to write a version that takes a fixed number of inputs and prints the average? Or are you asking for someone to write the whole thing for you?

Comment: Khelwood's remark is good. You need to provide at least a decent amount of trial-and-error code, SO is not for doing a whole homework/assignment website. Post your attempts and explain clearly where you have issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply u can do like this:

```
inputs = []
while True:
    ip =input()
    if ip == "end":
        break
    inputs.append(int(ip))
print(inputs)   
#print(sum(inputs)/len(inputs))
print(sum(inputs)/len(inputs) if len(inputs) > 0 else 0) #calc avg only if len of inputs is greater than zero
```

Input:

```
1
2
3
4
end
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]  #list of numbers
2.5   #avg of numbers
```

Comment: `print(sum(inputs)/len(inputs) if len(inputs) > 0 else 0)` to avoid the case someone types "end" as first